# What is meant by, "both variables follow a normal distribution" in Pearson's product moment correlation coefficient hypothesis tests?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, correlation

I am teaching myself further maths A Level Year 1 statistics from the OCR book (A).

Chapter $5$ is about Correlation and regression.

I get that the ppmcc is given by $r,$ which is just a number with $\vert r\vert < 1, $ and represents how closely a sample of data matches a straight line on a graph- a graph that represents the bivariate data.

Then it talks defines $\rho$ as the population correlation coefficient- so far so good.

Then it delves into how to carry out a hypothesis test for whether or not the two variables (of the bivariate data) have any correlation in the overall population, using the data from a sample. That is:

$H_0: \rho=0;\ H_1: \rho \neq 0$ for a two-tailed test, or either $H_1: \rho < 0$ or $H_1: \rho > 0$ for a one-tailed test.

Then it says, "If both variables follow a normal distribution then the table of critical values can be used to conduct the hypothesis test. The null hypothesis is rejected if the sample correlation coefficient is more than the critical value associated with the sample size $(n)$ and the significance level."

I get the idea of Hypothesis tests in general. However, here I don't know what it means by, "If both variables follow a normal distribution." What does this mean? If *what* follows a normal distribution?

The worked example given in the book is the following:

> Pheobe is looking for evidence that the population of cod $(c)$ and
> the population of tuna $(t)$ (where population is assessed by
> kilograms of fish caught), in various seas are negatively correlated.
> She observes eleven pairs of values and summarises her results:
>
> The statistical summary of results in the question is:

> $$ \sum c = 165,\ \sum c^2 = 2585,\ \sum t = 81,\ \sum t^2 = 757,\ \sum ct = 1184. $$
>
> $(a)$ find the ppmcc for the data.
>
> $(b)$ Conduct an appropriate test at the $5$% significance level.
>
> $(c)...$ is irrelevant to my question.

I don't understand what I'm meant to be checking follows a normal distribution in this question, in order to justify using the table of critical values.

The next section of the chapter is about Spearman's rank correlation coefficient, and it says, "when the samples are drawn from populations following a normal distribution, the ppmcc is a very good way to test for correlation".

Again, what does it mean for *a population to follow a normal distribution?* The reason this doesn't make sense to me is because usually we talk about an *attribute/ variable of something* following a normal distribution. For example, it makes sense to say, "the masses of tuna fish follow a normal distribution". But I don't get what it means by "a population follows a normal distribution". Anyway, now I am repeating myself, so I stop typing...

Comment: This must be the most wordy question I've ever asked.... It's definitely about maths though. Also, I'm not sure if it should be posted here or on cross-validated.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the population can be modelled by a normal or, more usually, an approximate-normal probability distribution (this is ok because “everything natural is basically normal” which is good enough for A level). For example, the population of cod and tuna following a bivariate normally distribution means that the probability of observing a set of values $(c,t)$ (e.g. $\{(c,t):0\le c\le100\wedge t\le c\}$) can be given by integrating the bivariate normal pdf with suitable parameters.

This is necessary since, under the hood, all these tests are following precise mathematical proofs where certain assumptions about the underlying data are necessary in order to show that, e.g., the probability distribution of $r$ is approximately (something) so that we can calculate critical values by integrating the pdf of (something). The further maths A level does not explain any of this as the exam boards prefer a wealth of formulae over any deep explanation... to be fair, for statistics the proofs are too dense for A level students (but I will never not be mad at the way they teach pure!!)

A more clear example (because I actually know what the distribution is ;) I believe pmcc asymptotically follows some kind of student’s T distribution but I’m not sure) of the second paragraph can be found in the $\chi^2$ tests. It can be shown (on Wikipedia there is a proof) that if you assume the observed data categories to follow a multinomial distribution with the probabilities given by your hypothetical distribution, then the probability that the observed $\chi^2$ statistic as taken from a sample is greater than a given value can be modelled (asymptotically for large samples) by a $\chi^2$ probability distribution with suitably many “degrees of freedom”.

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't help. Maybe I'll have a go at the Exercises first and then come back to this.

Comment: @AdamRubinson For the purposes of the A level you don’t need to worry. For the purposes of curiosity, it’s just saying that you can abstractly view the pair (cod,trout) as a bivariate normally distributed random variable. Maybe look up “multivariate normal distribution”. For anything deeper really you would want to investigate the proof of “correctness” (up to an approximation) for the pmcc test and its critical values (which will likely be a hard proof, certainly by A level standards).

Comment: “for the purposes of A Level you don’t need to worry.” That is what I am looking for, thanks!

Comment: @AdamRubinson But you do need to write it down if they ask you what the underlying assumptions are!

Comment: Yes it will have to be something to just memorise I suppose

Comment: Yeah. You probably want a full explanation - a deep insight into why the population needs to have a normal structure for the pmcc’s critical values to be “valid” - but this is quite complicated statistics involving (I assume) tricky integral estimation, Stirling approximation and the central limit theorem (if the proof of the $\chi^2$ test is anything to go by) - and all of that is way beyond Further Maths A level. So, like me, you just have to accept “it’s something that needs to be true or almost true in order for it to work”. Note that these tests are in themselves fudges, like all of stats

Comment: @AdamRubinson By that I mean that they work only as approximations or in the limit for larger samples. But again this is not something the A level student needs to worry about since “asymptotic equivalence” is not a word in the textbook :)

Comment: No, I just don't know what it means for a population to "have a normal structure". I feel like I need a specific, detailed example to explain exactly what this means.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I don’t think I can give you an example any better than the one already provided. Good luck and maybe try out cross validated if this doesn’t get much attention. I’ve upvoted but it’d still be worth a thought clarifying your post!

Comment: Please can you go into *more detail of what you mean* when you say, " the population of cod and tuna following a bivariate normally distribution means that the probability of observing a set of values $(c,t)$ (e.g. $\{(c,t):0\le c\le100\wedge t\le c\}$) can be given by integrating the bivariate normal pdf with suitable parameters."